# Passing down Polymer's HTML attributes to nested components

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a custom element `<x-marker>` with a `<paper-checkbox>` inside of it.

I want an `checked` attribute on my element to reflect down on the `<paper-checkbox>` but my solution doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

HTML:

```
<x-marker is-checked="<%= someBoolean %>"></x-marker>
```

Element:

```
<dom-module id="x-marker">

  <template>
    <div>
      <paper-checkbox id="checkbox"></paper-checkbox>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-marker',

      properties: {
        isChecked: String
      },

      listeners: {
        change: 'changeHandler'
      },

      attached: function() {
        if (this.isChecked === 'true') {
          this.$.checkbox.setAttribute('checked', this.isChecked);
        }
      },

      changeHandler: function (event, detail, sender) {
        //...
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

In Polymer 0.5 you could use `checked?="{{isChecked}}"`, but that doesn't seem to work in 1.0 anymore. Also hard coding `<paper-checkbox checked="false">` still *checks* the checkbox as long as the attribute is present. The value doesn't seem to matter, that's why the attribute itself has to be bound, and not its value.

I can't seem to figure this out, including treating the property as a string `=== 'true'` instead of a boolean, and bind it straight to the `<paper-checkbox>`

Answer (score 0):

In 1.0 you just need to use `checked="{{isChecked}}"`. You can implement it as follows:

HTML:

```
<x-marker checked="{{someBoolean}}"></x-marker>
```

ELEMENT:

```
<dom-module id="x-marker">

  <template>
    <div>
      <paper-checkbox id="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}">Check me</paper-checkbox>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-marker',

      properties: {
        checked: {
          type: Boolean,
          observer: '_checkChanged'
        }
      },

      _checkChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // Do something
      }

    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The checkboxes are always marked with setting the `checked="{{checked}}"` attribute. Note that my boolean value is just a string (from Ruby) and not a `{{binding}}`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Hmm...I tested it locally and it worked fine. The boolean value from Ruby is fine so long as you are only initialising the attribute. You won't benefit from Polymer's data-binding this way, but you seem to handle the binding ok manually. Possibly try set the `reflectToAttribute` and/or `notify` property on `checked` to propagate changes. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-reflection